# Linq Delete record with matches with another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have variable Reasons which has data in comma separated (Q12, Q14, .) (including dot). And I have a list order which has order reasons in it I want to check and delete the list if the order reasons in the list does not match with variable Reasons. Please let me know where I made mistake.

ReasonsToShow has data Q12,Q14,.

```
var Reasons = ReasonsToShow?.Split(',').ToList();
order.RemoveAll(r => Reasons.Any(x => x != r.OrderReason));
```

Comment: Assuming there are 2+ different items, the `Any(x => x != r.OrderReason)` will return always true (it will return true either in the first Reason or in the second). You could `r=> !Reasons.Any(x => x == r.OrderReason)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the

> Any(x => x != r.OrderReason)

will return always true is there are two or more Reasons. It will return true either in the first Reason or in the second. Consider this Reasons data:

- Q12
- Q14

The `Any` function will loop thru the data and return `true` if any of the items matches your `x => x != r.OrderReason` criteria.

If you `Any(x => x != "Q14")` then the `Any` funtion will return `true` because of the first item ("Q12" != "Q14").

If you want to make sure the item is not in any of the elements you could:

```cs
order.RemoveAll(r=> ! Reasons.Any(x => x == r.OrderReason));
```

or if you prefer checking for differences

```cs
order.RemoveAll(r => Reasons.All(x => x != r.OrderReason));
```

Comment: The list has 3 data Q12 , Q14 , .

Comment: @user2432361 the logical problem with 3 items is the same. The important thing in my answer is not the final code, but the description of the problem. Just think of what will evaluate the `Any` statement in each iteration of the list.